# Haskell - Deriving automatically Integral from an enumation of type constructors

Tags: haskell, types

I would like to know if there is a way to make GHC automatically derive the instance of integral from a data type of the form :

```
data = A | B | C | D
```

so that fromIntegral A = 0, fromIntegral B = 1, etc. ?

Using

```
data MyType = A | B | C | D deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Real, Integral)
```

produce the error

> Can't make a derived instance of ‘Integral MyType’: 
>    ‘Integral’ is not a derivable class
>
> In the data declaration for ‘MyType’

(even with the extension GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755525/how-to-write-a-derivable-class)

Comment: Yes, I had. It says that there is no general solution for deriving from any type, and that in the case of a newType you can use the GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving extension. But it doesn't says that there isn't an extension in GHC allowing automatic derivation for types of the form A|B|C.

Comment: What is wrong with the newtype wrapper approach?

Comment: could `fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int` serve as a solution for your Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is a function such that `f A == 0`, `f B == 1`, etc., you can use [`fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum).

The `Integral` type class is for types you can actually add, subtract, divide... In your case, there isn't a very sensible implementation of these things. If you wanted to implement them as arithmetic modulo `1 + fromEnum maxBound`... well, I don't recommend doing that, if your `Enum` represents anything *but* those numbers, and if they do, the [`modular-arithmetic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic) package already implements what you need.

Comment: To add to this, you can derive `Enum`.

Comment: Thanks you, fromEnum :: a -> Int and toEnum :: Int -> a are exactly what I need :-)